# Require old password when setting a new password to a specific user in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c, change-password

Does Oracle 12 support having the old password required when changing a password to a specific user?

What I would like:

```
ALTER USER user_a IDENTIFIED BY secret123;
-- ERROR, missing old password

ALTER USER user_a IDENTIFIED BY secret456 REPLACE secret123;
-- OK

ALTER USER user_b IDENTIFIED BY secret789;
-- OK, since user_b does not require old password when changing it
```

Thanks!

Comment: At which user do you run these commands?

Comment: Presumably this would be for users changing their own passwords. I'm not aware of any such facility, but this is really a DBA question.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: yes, it's certainly up to the DBA to administer the password settings, but it won't hurt if programmers understand the possibilities, don't you think?

Comment: @wolφi I guess so. I have to admit I wasn't aware of the `replace` clause of `alter user identified by` and how it is affected by the presence of a password verification function, so I learned something today.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson: Me too, I had to read it up and try it out. (I'm not a DBA, but annoyed when the passwords in our (empty) dev database expire and have to be changed...)

Comment: @wolφi I agree, sometimes it is similar to @metoo;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is supported since Oracle 9i, when a function was introduced that checks a new password for complexity and optionally for difference to the old password. As Oracle stores only hashes, not the passwords, it cannot compare old and new passwords unless the user supplies it during the change.

So, all users with a `PROFILE` where the `PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION` is set are required to have the old password, even if this function doesn't check any passwords:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION always_true (
  username     VARCHAR2, 
  password     VARCHAR2, 
  old_password VARCHAR2) RETURN boolean IS
BEGIN
  RETURN TRUE;
END always_true;
/

CREATE PROFILE always_true 
  LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION always_true;

CREATE USER user_a IDENTIFIED BY secret123 PROFILE always_true;
GRANT CREATE SESSION to user_a;
```

Now `user_a` has to specify the old password:

```
ALTER USER user_a IDENTIFIED BY secret123;
ORA-28221: REPLACE not specified

ALTER USER user_a IDENTIFIED BY secret456 REPLACE secret123;
User altered.
```

A user with a profile without `PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION` or this parameter set to `NULL` doesn't have to specify the old password:

```
CREATE PROFILE without_function 
  LIMIT PASSWORD_VERIFY_FUNCTION NULL;

CREATE USER user_b IDENTIFIED BY secret123 PROFILE without_function;
GRANT CREATE SESSION to user_b;
```

Now `user_b` can change his/her password without having the old password:

```
ALTER USER user_b IDENTIFIED BY secret789;
User altered.
```

The second option is to have the privilege `ALTER USER`, but that is only for administrators, as they can change all the passwords of all account.

Comment: From our database we have ALTER USER. And this is actually the case; not allowing a certain user to be changed without specifying the old password. But then, what if the user runs ALTER PROFILE and changes it to DEFAULT first...

Comment: If the user has ALTER PROFILE, then this is of course possible. However, normally only SYS, DBA and similar users have the priv ALTER PROFILE.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [docu](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4003.htm#SQLRF01103) says

> You can omit the REPLACE clause if you are setting your own password for the first time or you have the ALTER USER system privilege and you are changing another user's password. However, unless you have the ALTER USER system privilege, you must always specify the REPLACE clause if a password complexity verification function has been enabled ...

so the answer would be - add a `password verification function` to those users that should provide the old password (and revoke the *password change system privilege* from them).